# How to lower a background image from the top of the containing element?

Tags: css

Here is the html:

```
<section class="bg">
   <h3>this is heading</h3>
   <div>other content</div>
</section>
```

I have the following for my background image:

```
.bg {
   background: url("img/watercolor-bkgrd.png") center top / 100% 75%  no-repeat
}
```

Now I would like to position the background image slightly lower from the top (for example: 100px) so that h3 heading will not stay on top the background image. How can I make it happen without modifying the html structure? Please note that I have to keep what is already in the above css such as centering the image horizontally, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [background position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) offset value.

This does require that you **know** the height of the element above though.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h3 {
  height: 60px;
  background: lightblue;
  opacity: .5;
}

.bg {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(http://www.placebacon.net/400/200?image=0);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top 60px;
}
```

```html
<section class="bg">
  <h3>this is heading</h3>
  <div>other content</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi Paulie_D, thanks for the background position offset idea. Yes, it works. I never used it before. Thank you! One quick question, can I incorporate everything (including background position offset) in a shorthand?

Answer (score 2):

Just change "top" to "100px" or whatever value you want to move it by.

See this working snippet (where I use 80px):

```css
.bg {
height:400px; /* for testing */
   background: url("http://oi67.tinypic.com/28a11js.jpg") center 80px / 100% 75%  no-repeat
}
```

```html
<section class="bg">
   <h3>this is heading</h3>
   <div>other content</div>
</section>
```

This is setting the `background-position` properties inline in the same way that you are in your own code.

The problem is making sure the image is always under the `<h3>` element: You could make the `<h3>` element a fixed height and use the same value for your background position.

**Unknown height of h3 element**

If you don't know the height of the `<h3>` element, how about adding the image as  background to the `<div>` underneath the `<h3>` like this:

```css
.bg div{
    height:400px; /* for testing */
       background: url("http://oi67.tinypic.com/28a11js.jpg") center top / 100% 75%  no-repeat
    }
```

```html
    <section class="bg">
       <h3>this is heading</h3>
       <div>other content</div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Hi FluffyKitten, thanks for helping me. The background position offset is the solution. Cheers!

Comment: @curious1 Glad to help! If you don't know the height of the `<h3>` element though, the second snippet in my code shows how you can achieve the same effect by applying the background to the div, meaning the image will *always* be under the h3 :)

Comment: FluffyKitten, thanks for the idea! In my case, I just wanted to move the image down a little. H3 may will stay on top of part of the background image.

Comment: @curious1 no problem, It was just an alternative option in case you needed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Youre looking for the css property "background-position" ([Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position))

This allows you to set the initial top and left positions of your background image in the div.

background-position: left top;
Just add the following to your .bg class:

```
background-position: 0 100px;
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for helping me. The background position offset is the solution. Cheers!